# How do I add metadata to my own kodi addon where my movies are

Tags: python, video, lib, kodi

So I am trying to follow how I can install this file called script.module.metadatautils so i can put in my add don on kodi which i have imported movies too but it wont work and i dont want to have to put my own art work in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your asking, but maybe you want to add `script.module.metadatautils` to the dependencies of your `addon.xml`
http://kodi.wiki/view/Addon.xml#.3Cimport.3E